# KeyboardHook как конвертировать клавиши?

Tags: c#

Чтобы не писать длинный кусок кода, можно ли это конвертировать как нибудь?

```
private void keyUp(KeyboardHook.VKeys key)
    {
    if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.SPACE)
    {
    textBox1.Text += " ";
    }
    else if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.KEY_0)
    {
    textBox1.Text += "0";
    }
    else if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.KEY_1)
    {
    textBox1.Text += "1";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно сделать словарь соответсвия KeyboardHook.VKeys строке, и к нему обращаться.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<KeyboardHook.VKeys, string> VKEYS_MAP = 
   new Dictionary <KeyboardHook.VKeys, string> { [KeyboardHook.VKeys.SPACE] = " ", ...};

private void keyUp(KeyboardHook.VKeys key)
{
    if (VKEY_MAP.ContainsKey(key))
       textBox1.Text += VKEYS_MAP[key];
}
```

Comment: А как проверить смену языка ? чтобы и для Русского и для Английского было!

Comment: @TriX http://yal.cc/csharp-get-current-keyboard-layout/

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, А специальные клавиши как можно из Вашего примера вытащить?

Answer (score 1):

Я вот ещё как попробовал)

```
string[] KeyToChar = new string[100]; 
KeyToChar[(int)VKeys.SPACE] = " ";
KeyToChar[(int)VKeys.KEY_0] = "0";
KeyToChar[(int)VKeys.KEY_1] = "1";
```

Но не читает такие знаки как: [!"№;%:?*()+_]